# Fadein fadeout зацикливание при наведение на картинку

Tags: jquery, изображения

```
var timer;
function blink()
{
    $("#menu_bla").fadeOut();
    $("#menu_bla").fadeIn();

    timer = setTimeout(blink, 0)
}
```

Вроде бы работает, но вопрос в том что мне прийдется писать код 10 раз для разных
кнопок?

```
$("#logo_left").mouseover(function () {
blink();
    });
```

может как то параметр передавать?
Так не работает в функции.

```
$(this).fadeOut();
$(this).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

следите за контекстом и областью видимости, таймер я прям к элементу привязал.

```
function blink() {
    var $that = $(this);
    $that.stop().fadeOut().fadeIn(

    function () {
        $that.data('timer', setTimeout(function () {
            blink.call($that);
        }));
    });

}

function blink_stop() {
    clearTimeout($(this).finish().fadeIn().data('timer'));
}

$('#1').hover(blink, blink_stop);
$('#3').hover(blink, blink_stop);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mq4f2/

## большая просьба

в следующий раз делайте демонстрационный jsfiddle сами.

---

вот вариант на который меня натолкнул [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)

```
function blink() {
    $(this).stop().fadeToggle().queue(blink);
}

function blink_stop() {
    $(this).stop().finish().fadeIn(0);
}

$('#1, #2').hover(blink, blink_stop);
$('#3').hover(blink, blink_stop);
```

Comment: Красивый код, злобное жонглирование переменными, почти сишное)

Можно еще юзать не таймаут, а onFinish ( `blink(function() { if (mouseover) blink(); });`). Должно быть еще злее)

Comment: учту, спасибо большок.

Comment: @Sh4dow вы [это имели ввиду](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mq4f2/4/) ?

Comment: а почему работает [это](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mq4f2/5/) я не до конца понимаю.

Comment: @eicto, не я [о рекурсии](http://jsfiddle.net/arwmF/1/), родимой) Почему-то не получилось заставить работать с `fadeIn`, но суть передал.

(увидел update, да, почти то же самое)

Comment: @Sh4dow [ещё уменьшил](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/arwmF/2/) :)

Comment: @eicto, [и еще чуть-чуть колдунства](http://jsfiddle.net/arwmF/3/) )

Answer (score 0):

Если кнопки из одной и той же тематики, проще навесить на них общий класс, а навешивать события по классу, например....  .button, тогда

```
$(".button").mouseover(function () {
    $(".button").fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeOut(); // или наоборот, или как вам там надо
});
```

Comment: тоже не  в тему.

Comment: в след раз
@Sleepless, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 0):

[Пишем плагин для jQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/158235/)

```
jQuery.fn.myFadeOut = function() {
    this.mouseover(function () {
        blink();
    });
}
$("#logo_left").myFadeOut();
```

Comment: и при чем тут плагин ?